# If you set a style for a pre or div once, do you need to set again?

Tags: html, pre

for example, if i do:

```
pre style="white-space:pre-wrap;"
```

at the beginning of my first pre block, would this apply to all pre blocks? it doesn't seem to have the effect I want.

Comment: If that's inlined on your tag then yes, every one. OR you could use CSS and apply them for all `pre` tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if you define your style directly inside your `<pre>` tag, it will only be applied to this element.

Define your CSS properties in a `<style>` block, and it will be applied to all `<pre>` elements:

```
<style>
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
</style>
```

Simply place this block inside the `<head>` of your HTML document.

Comment: @cybters I am not familiar with Aurora clients. Did you include the <style> tag? Is the website displayed correctly in other browsers, e.g. Chrome?